# Finding $f(x)$ such that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\sum_{k=a}^{b}f(k)$

Tags: integration, summation, special-functions

Does there exist any method  to find the function $f(x)$ which satisfies 
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\sum_{k=a}^{b}f(k)$$

For example
$$\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(k)}{k}=\pi$$

Comment: The trivial function $f=\Bbb 0$ works.  Or are you asking for a method of generating all triples $(f,a,b)$ which satisfy your condition?  Or are you asking for a way of verifying whether a given triple $(f,a,b)$ satisfies the condition without explicitly evaluating the integral and sum?

Comment: What does $\sum_{k=\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ mean?

Comment: It's pretty clear that it's a typo and OP meant $\sum\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sinc}(k) = \pi$

Comment: is $k$ integer?

Comment: The limits on a definite integral don't mean the same thing as the limits on a discrete sum. How do you handle the case $a=-\frac12$ and $b=\frac12$? I would think $k$ would then take on only the value $k=0$. One usually means to include only the integers contained in $[a,b]$ for the discrete sum.

Comment: http://carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/Preprints/Papers/Published-InPress/Sinc-sums/Related/boas.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Unless we allow [Kroneker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#Integral_representations) 'singularity' functions, it's easy to see $f(k)=0$ for all integer $k$ since $f(a) = \sum_{k=a}^af(k)=\int_a^a f(x)dx = 0$.

Hence with $a, b, k$ integers, only such functions are those whose integrals vanish over every integer range and is $0$ at all integers.

An example:
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{l}0&\text{if }x\in\mathbb{Z}\\sin(2\pi x)&\text{if }\lfloor x\rfloor\text{ is even}\\2(x-[x])-1&\text{if }\lfloor x\rfloor\text{ is odd}\end{array}\right.$$

You can get creative.